# How can I install Qt onto another computer but in different directories?

Tags: c++, qt

I used the online download of Qt to install it on my desktop but now I also want it on my laptop and I am unsure of how I can do that without having to re-download. My internet connection is crap and I don't even know if the Laptop will allow me to considering that it is one issued by my school and not all downloads work. Please help! I tried copying all the files over to the laptop but now all the settings are weird because the computer I am using doesnt have (or allow access) to the C drive.

Comment: I was wondering if maybe the online installer puts the non extracted files somewhere or maybe I could completely reset it on the new computer. Qt actually opens its just that when I make a new project it wont work because of the kit and an "incorrect Qt version problem when adding the correct Qmake path.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at where does an installed version of Qt store the paths.

It seems that you need to change the following:

- `Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/[compiler]/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_[module].pri`

  In each of those files, change the line that begins with `QT.[module].rpath`.